# Kubernetes K3s and api-versions not included, what to do?

Tags: kubernetes, vps, k3s

going through a nice tutorial where I came across an unexpected (no surprise eh?) surprise which I am trying to fix.

```
error: resource mapping not found for name: "letsencrypt-staging" namespace: "default" from "letsencrypt-issuer-staging.yaml": no matches for kind "ClusterIssuer" in version "cert-manager.io/v1alpha2"
```

I have installed the latest cert-manager versions v1.10.1

```
k apply -f https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.10.1/cert-manager.yaml


k apply -f https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.10.1/cert-manager.crds.yaml
```

However when I do

```
k api-versions | grep cert
  acme.cert-manager.io/v1
  cert-manager.io/v1
  certificates.k8s.io/v1
```

I do not have the cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 I am looking for

Now when I am reading more and more I saw someone telling me that k3s does not have alpha/beta versions included and I have to use another single node cluster.

- Is this correct?
- If yes, which one is a good alternative for learning k8s? (I am trying to deploy a single node cluster on a vps)

Last idea is to use an api-version I DO have, but how should I do that? This is my current issuer.yaml

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-staging
  namespace: default
spec:
  acme:
    email: yes@mail.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: staging-issuer-account-key
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    http01: {}
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: traefik
        selector: {}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You appear to have api `cert-manager.io/v1`, which would appear to be a more recent version of the `cert-manager` api. Seems like you should be using that instead of `v1alpha2`.

Comment: @larsks indeed, it was as simple as using cert-manager.io/v1. Thanks and sorry for late reaction...holidays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @larsks said you should use the latest version that you have installed

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
Spec:
```

And for alpha/beta versions you can use them in k3s also but will be older version which will not be encouraged ,

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v0.15.1/cert-manager.yaml
```

From above version you can use alpha version as below:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
Spec:
```

Attaching respected blogs of [v1](https://blog.differentpla.net/blog/2022/02/06/cert-manager/), [v1 alpha2](https://blog.internetz.me/posts/my-road-to-self-hosted-kubernetes-with-k3s_cert-manager/) for your reference.

Comment: Holidays...late reaction but this helps and made me to use the latest version thank you